# Tried to reset Admin PW, but Ubuntu isn't recognizing Admin account. How do I fix this?

Tags: login, password, password-recovery

I recently got a setup with Ubuntu v15.04, but I don't know the admin password. I have some background in IT, and know how to reset it. (BIOS, hold Shift, Adv. Ubuntu -> Memory -> Root, type `passwd *root*` where root is account name, enter and verify new password.)
  However, when I enter `passwd Aviator` (account name), it says `'Aviator' is not a user`. I need this computer, how do I get Ubuntu to recognize the account?
   Thanks.
NOTE: The computer does not have WiFi or Ethernet. I CAN access the Guest account and use Terminal, but it has been no help. I'd really rather not have to hack my own computer...

EDIT: Found true username of admin, 'fltsim01'. Entered `passwd fltsim01`, was asked for New Unix Password, then to Verify, got the following:

`passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
root@fltsim01-MS-7593:~#`

(Note: `root@fltsim01-MS-7593:~#` is given at Terminal startup, and whenever ready for new command.)

Eyoung, do you want the whole thing? It's 24 two-word lines.

Comment: Please post the output of `awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd`

Comment: The username is almost certainly all lower case  (don't confuse it with the [GECOS fullname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field). If in doubt, try `ls /home` (the account's home directory name is *usually* the same as the username).

Answer (score 1):

`passwd` doesn't take the full name of your account; it takes the *username* (and AFAIK, in Ubuntu, usernames can't start with a capital letter). You can get the corresponding a full name's corresponding username with this command:

```
grep ':PUT FULL NAME HERE' /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

(replacing `PUT FULL NAME HERE` with the full name you want to search for)

Alternatively, if you don't know the full name you want, you can get a list of usernames and their corresponding full names, seperated by a `:`, with this command:

```
cut -d: -f1,5 /etc/passwd | cut -d, -f1
```

In this case, your username is probably `aviator` (with a lowercase 'a').

P.S. Ubuntu 15.04 is EOL. It shouldn't affect `passwd`, but you should upgrade to the latest version (currently 16.04), or at least go to 14.04 or 12.04 if you can.